# App no longer authorised or listed in Location Services Apps

Tags: ios, xcode, geolocation

I have been updating an app that uses location services. Once of the changes didn't show up when I ran it, so I deleted it from the phone, and cleaned the xcode project.

When I now run it, the app is no longer authorized to use Location Services. When I look in settings, the app is no longer listed as an app that requires Location Services.

I had updated the info.plist file and added the background mode and device capabilities - but when I return these to how they were, the app still has the same problem.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend starting your project again from scratch but you can copy all your resource files (.h, .m, interface file, images, sounds, anything else) accross to the new project. Build and run it and it should e fine.

Reply if it doesn't!

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back to you! I have tried moving everything across to a new project and it still does not show up in the location services list...